# In Riverpod 2.0 Flutter, is it possible to create multiple NotifierProvider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-riverpod

Before Riverpod is using `build_runner`, it was possible to create multiple provider that using one class of (State)Notifier. like the code below,

```
class Counter extends StateNotifier<int>{
  Counter(): super(0);
  
  void increment() => state++;
}


final counter1Provider = StateNotifierProvider<Counter,int>((ref) => Counter());
final counter2Provider = StateNotifierProvider<Counter,int>((ref) => Counter());

Counter counter1 = ref.watch(counter1Provider);
Counter counter2 = ref.watch(counter2Provider);
```

Then the Riverpod is updated to 2.0 and now support code generation, the `Counter` class can be like this.

```
@riverpod
class Counter extends _$Counter {

  @override
  int build(){
    return 0;
  }

  void increment(){
    state ++;
  }


Counter counter = ref.watch(counterProvider);
```

It seems like the `StateNotifier` and `StateNotifierProvider` is became into one `Provider`, it possible to create another `Provider` that return the `Counter` class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need.
With the new annotation, you only need the following to access to the class:

```
ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).increment();
```

This will call the increment() method into your notifier class.

Hope this can help.